# Reduce execution time when locating element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588355/reduce-execution-time-of-pandas-code) here, and I identified the bottleneck in my script, so I ask my question with more clarity. My code looks like this :

```
temp=df["IPs"]
times_db_all = [df[temp == user]["time"].values for user in user_db.values]

%timeit times_db_all = [df_temp[temp == user]["time"].values for user in user_db.values[0:3]]
1 loops, best of 3: 848 ms per loop #848ms for 3 users !!
```

my df looks like this :

```
IPs        time
1.1.1.1    datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, tzinfo=tzutc()),
1.1.1.1    datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 1, 7, 30, tzinfo=tzutc()),
3.3.3.3    datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 5, 58, 52, tzinfo=tzutc()),
1.1.1.1    datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 10, 16, 22, 56, tzinfo=tzutc())
4.4.4.4    datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 10, 16, 23, 01, tzinfo=tzutc())
....
```

with `user_db.values = ["1.1.1.1","3.3.3.3","4.4.4.4",...]`

The goal is to have the list of all the timestamp in the "time" column of df, for each user. I then use this list to check how long the user stayed on the website and how many times he visited :

```
       IP       time
    1.1.1.1    [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, tzinfo=tzutc()), 
               datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 1, 7, 30, tzinfo=tzutc()),   
               datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 10, 16, 22, 56, tzinfo=tzutc())]
    3.3.3.3    [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 5, 58, 52, tzinfo=tzutc())]
    4.4.4.4    [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 10, 16, 23, 01, tzinfo=tzutc())]
```

My issue is that I have 3.5 millions row, and it slows the execution of this line a lot.

What could be a faster way to do the same thing?

Comment: Any reason why you're not just grouping by IP?

Comment: No reason, can you provide an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby` as below ..

```
# create a random dataframe with your data
def create_ip(): return '.'.join([str(randint(0,255)) for i in range(4)])
def create_dt(): return datetime.datetime(2017, 1, randint(1,10), randint(0,23), randint(0,59))
df = pd.DataFrame({'ip': [create_ip() for i in range(10)]*10,
                   'time': [create_dt() for i in range(100)]})

# use groupby
df.groupby('ip')['time'].apply(list)

[Out]
ip
127.140.64.48      [2017-01-10 04:23:00, 2017-01-03 16:55:00, 201...
150.206.39.49      [2017-01-02 03:07:00, 2017-01-07 21:59:00, 201...
186.188.130.77     [2017-01-04 13:03:00, 2017-01-05 19:23:00, 201...
190.152.20.150     [2017-01-02 12:47:00, 2017-01-03 23:55:00, 201...
208.235.194.243    [2017-01-10 08:55:00, 2017-01-08 08:07:00, 201...
223.138.217.41     [2017-01-02 22:36:00, 2017-01-10 02:16:00, 201...
226.176.251.244    [2017-01-03 12:08:00, 2017-01-07 06:14:00, 201...
24.21.19.130       [2017-01-07 14:05:00, 2017-01-05 04:25:00, 201...
50.167.31.84       [2017-01-10 03:28:00, 2017-01-03 11:05:00, 201...
83.56.204.14       [2017-01-08 12:46:00, 2017-01-01 03:05:00, 201...
Name: time, dtype: object

# compare times
%timeit df.groupby('ip')['time'].apply(list)
[Out] 100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop

%timeit times_db_all = [df[df['ip'] == user]['time'].values for user in df['ip'].unique()]
[Out] 100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
```

You might be able to make this even faster by setting `'ip'` as your index and then grouping on the index.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be utilizing a for loop to do individual boolean selection as you are doing. The `isin` method is designed exactly for this purpose and will select rows that match any of the values in `user_db`. Try it instead

```
df.loc[df['IPs'].isin(user_db.values), "time"]
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this gives me a single dataframe with all the timestamp for each users. I need an independant list of timestamp for each users.

Comment: The above solution only selects the `time` column. If you want all the columns of the original dataframe back then just do `df.loc[df['IPs'].isin(user_db.values)]`